# Unicode insert of Russian into Oracle DB with Python 2.7

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, unicode, cx-oracle

I have a problem unicode russian word. I have python 2.7.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
teh2 = ['Col1','Col2']
va = [(108, u"русский")]
for i in va:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Mytable("+ teh2[0] + "," + teh2[1] +") VALUES('"+ str(i[0]) + "', '"+ str(i[1]) + "')")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Never ever construct SQL strings with `+` ir other string formatting. It leads to injection vulnerabilities. See the documentation of your database adapter to see how it is done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Characters Sets and National Language Support (NLS)](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html) in the cx_Oracle documentation.  You probably want to connect using something like:

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

The character set of the database also has a role to play, since inserted data will be mapped into that character set.

Regarding the string concatenation - as noted in a comment, never, ever do this.  See the warning and links in [SQL Queries](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#sql-queries).